# Keepass kdb support?

Tags: 16.04, keepass, keepassx

Is there a way to open a `kdb` file on ubuntu 16.04 without having to convert it to `kdbx`? I want to keep using `kdb` because that is the only format i can open on a windows computer that i have no admin access to install something else compatible with `kdbx`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up installing an older version of KeePassX from this URL:

Package Page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/keepassx/download

Direct Download Link: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keepassx/keepassx_0.4.3+dfsg-0.1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb (it is for Trusty, but works well in Xenial)

The newer version (2.X) dropped support for `kdb` files.

The following command will pin the package to the older version so that it doesn't get updated when you do `apt-get upgrade`:

```
# hold package, so that it doesn't get upgraded
echo "keepassx hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

# for posterity, same as above
apt-mark hold keepassx

# since aptitude doesn't respect the above
aptitude hold keepassx
```

Comment: Thanks @adeelx!
This has been a problem for me. I use keepass cross platform. Still need to work with version 1 files.

Answer (score 6):

For those of you who prefer to compile old or missing packages or who want to have both KeepassX version 2 and 0.4, you may follow this instructions:

- Install the build dependencies (`sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev libxtst-dev qt4-make`).
- Download the source code of the last 0.4 version (0.4.4) [keepassx-0.4.4.tar.gz](https://www.keepassx.org/releases/0.4.4/keepassx-0.4.4.tar.gz)
- Decompress it (`tar xvf keepassx-0.4.4.tar.gz`).
- Get into the directory (`cd keepassx-0.4.4/`).
- Edit the file `src/lib/random.cpp` to add the line `#include <unistd.h>` around line 22 (this is a requiremente to compile with the version of GCC in latest Ubuntu versions).
- Run qmake to create the Makefile (`qmake PREFIX=/usr/local`).
- Run make to build the executable (`make`).
- Install the executable (`sudo make install`). This will put the binary executable in `/usr/local/bin/keepassx`.

Now, you can create a new launcher icon to `/usr/local/bin/keepassx` to run the 0.4 version. (You may need to edit the old keepassx launcher to point to `/usr/bin/keepassx` to run version 2).

This should work at least for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) to 17.10 (Artful).

This is a screenshot of both versions running side by side in Ubuntu Mate 16.04: [image]