# Converting KeePass data base

Tags: keepassx

I can get both KeePassX 2 and KeePassX 0.4 from https://www.keepassx.org/downloads, KeePassX 2 can be found in Ubuntu software center meaning easily installing, but my data base (or the passwords file finishing with .kdb) is created by version 0.4, can I convert .kdb file from  KeePassX 0.4.4 to KeePassX 2? How to compile KeePassX 0.4 Source code if I can't convert .kdb? file ?

Comment: Have you tried opening your `.kbd` file in KeePassX 2? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775758/keepass-kdb-support?rq=1 should help you troubleshoot issues opening an older `.kbd` file in a new version of KeePassX. But your first step is definitely to try opening the file in the current version. If you encounter errors, see if anyone else has solved them here.

Comment: I would recommand switch to KeepassXC and import v1 database.